# Create reminder in windows runtime

Tags: windows-runtime, reminders, windows-phone-8.1

I am in the process of porting an app from windows phone 8 silverlight to windows phone 8.1 runtime.
Before I could create reminders like this:

```
Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
reminder.Title = titleTextBox.Text;
reminder.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;

// Register the reminder with the system.
ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

How would I do this in windows phone 8.1 runtime?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there's no equivalent for Windows phone 8.1 runtime

[Migrating your Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Runtime XAML app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Now you must use toast notifications using the new Action Center feature

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.notifications.aspx)

[Action Center QuickStart](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Action-Center-Quickstart-b15089f2)